# How can I access the Excel API from a custom function on Windows?

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, custom-functions-excel

I am trying to use the Excel API in my custom function in a manner similar to what is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/call-excel-apis-from-custom-function).

It works perfectly well on the Mac version of Excel and the Web version however, it doesn't work on the Windows version.

On Windows, I see `reference error Excel is not defined` in the debugging log when the custom function tries to access the context with `var context = new Excel.RequestContext();`.

How can I get this to work on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to call Excel API from a custom function on Windows, you need to config your add-in to use shared runtime. You can refer to the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/share-data-and-events-between-custom-functions-and-the-task-pane-tutorial).